# Getting the key in firebase to android studio

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

How do i get the ID of under the Cats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cats");

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     String keys=datas.getKey();
   }
 }
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
 });
```

The dataSnapshot here is referring to `Cats`, then you loop inside of the direct children which is the id in this case and retrieve it using `getKey()`